# Getting the exact position of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I want to get the exact positions of the div using its class name. Here is the screenshot.[image: screenshot]. My script which is finding a div position is highlighted in yellow and the div i am looking for is at the bottom highlighted red. Since my script is placed above the div so i am finding the parent div of the document and then comparing the div class with the div class i am looking for and thats how i am getting the positions. The positions are not exact. For example if the Top and Left position of the div is 50,150 then i am getting like 55,155.

```
function getPosition(element) {
            var xPosition = 0;
            var yPosition = 0;
            var left = 0;
            var top = 0;
            var i = 0;
            while (element) {
                xPosition = (element.offsetLeft);
                yPosition = (element.offsetTop);
                console.log("TOP Pos: "+yPosition+"Left Pos: "+xPosition);
                if (i == 1) {
                    left = xPosition;
                    top = yPosition;
               }
                element = element.offsetParent;
                i++;
            }
            return {
                x: left,
                y: top
            };
        }
```

And this is how i am using this method.

```
 function ReadDivPos(selector) {
            var _divPos = "";
            var parentDoc = window;
            while (parentDoc !== parentDoc.parent) {
                parentDoc = parentDoc.parent;
            }
            parentDoc = parentDoc.document;
            var parentDiv = parentDoc.getElementsByTagName('div');
            var divs = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < parentDiv.length; i++) {
                if (parentDiv[i].className == "content") {
                    var pos = getPosition(parentDiv[i]);
                    var x = pos["x"];
                    var y = pos["y"];
                    console.log("Values+ Top: " + y + " Left: " + x);
                    var w = parentDiv[i].offsetWidth;
                    _divPos += x + "," + w + "," + y + "," + (x + w) + ","+window.screen.availWidth+"\\n";
                }
            }
            console.log("Values+ x: " + _divPos);
            return _divPos;
        }
```

This is working fine but i am just wondering is there any other better way to make it done using jquery or any other method. Thanks in advance!.

Comment: If you're trying to retrieve the position of an element relative to the document you can use jQuery.offset http://api.jquery.com/offset/ or if relative to it's closest positioned parent then use jQuery.position http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: i dont get it why anyone can give me -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See :

```js
$(function() {
  var x = $(".target").offset().left,
      y = $(".target").offset().top;
  
  $(".target").html("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
});
```

```css
body
{
  padding: 0;
}

.target
{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  line-height: 7em;
  text-align: center;
  left: 100px;
  top: 20px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="target"></div>
```